# Shipping .NET framework with the installer issue (for windows 8)

Tags: .net, inno-setup

I'm creating a stand-alone installer for my .NET application that automatic install .NET framework 2.0 and my application all in one.

The installer work by checking Window has installed .NET Framework or not, if not then install dotnetfx20.exe (for window xp ) or enable it using Dism command line (for window 7 and above):

```
if (Windows7 or Windows8) then
begin
  Exec('Dism', ' /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /NoRestart', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
end;
```

However, i found some exception with this method. Today my customer complain that they can't install our software on Windows 8. And after checked his computer, i realized that the issue come while enable .NET Framework :

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Windows\system32>dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3
>   /All /NoRes tart
>
> Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031
>
> Enabling feature(s) [===========================66.6%======
>   ]
>
> Error: 0x800f0906
>
> The source files could not be downloaded. Use the "source" option to
>   specify the location of the files that are required t o restore the
>   feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

After searching on the internet, i found a manually solution is insert the Window 8 disk to install .NET framework offline. But my customer does not have a Window 8 DVD in there so i cannot help him, and i need to comeback later to give him a Window 8 disk.

Return to my stand-alone installer. Because I'm going to sell my app world-wide. I cannot shipping a window 8 disk to each customer and don't want to spend much time for fixing manually.  I would like to fix my installer so it can install .NET framework offline on Window 8 without connect to internet. I've tried to run dotnetfx20.exe/dotnetfx35.exe to install offline on Window 8 but it doesn't work. So is there anyway to workaround with this issue?

Comment: Addin-Express Installers can be solution to this problem.

Comment: Why not move to .NET 4? It's [supported back to XP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=17718) and you'll have a far easier ride.

Comment: I've had similar issue with windows 8 fighting against .NETv3.5 installer. Wasn't able to solve it; our shop moved to .NETv4 and the issue went away.

Comment: Sometimes this error occurs when a computer is in Domain and the policies are set to download Windows Updates via Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) instead of Contacting Windows Update Directly

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever .net 4 support only window xp sp3